# Similarity transformation, symmetric and diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a orthogonal transformation C such that (Cinverse).A.(C) is a diagonal matrix D, then should A be symmetric? Is there a way to prove it? I have found many proofs of the converse of the above statement, but not for this. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

For a square orthogonal matrix $C$, $C^{-1}=C^T$, so you’re really asking if $CDC^T$, where $D$ is diagonal, is symmetric. Let’s see: $$(CDC^T)^T = (C^T)^TD^TC^T = CDC^T.$$